# Force width of flex item to be 50%

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a flex based container where the items should be expanded on hover with an animation. All items should first be of equal width dependent on the total width of the container. When hovering an item, the item hovered should be exactly 50% of the total container width, with the rest of the items not hovered being shrunk to fill the remaining space.

This seems like a very easy thing to do, but I can't really wrap my head around how to achieve the result I'm after.

I've tried this code: https://codepen.io/tobiasger/pen/xxRWxpV

```
.flex-container {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  height:300px;
}

.flex-item {
  flex:1;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.flex-item:hover {
  flex-basis:50%;
}
```

But the `flex-basis` is not resulting in 50% of the container. I'm not sure what it's basing it's percentage on, it seems closer to the window width than the actual container width.

I've also tried applying a `min-width` value of 50% to the hovered item, but that doesn't seem to be possible to animate.

The goal is to not have to create specific classes for containers depending on how many items they contain. If it's possible to always force the hovered item to be exactly 50% of the container width while having the rest of the items fill the remaining 50% equally, and also animate this width change, I would be very happy!

Comment: Did you try width:50%?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add `flex-grow:0;` to `.flex-item:hover`.

```
.flex-item:hover {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

This works too

```
.flex-item:hover {
  flex: 0 50%;
}
```

Comment: It kind of works, but the element grows bigger in an instant and then animates the shrink to 50%, so it creates a kind of nasty animation unfortunately.

Comment: What browser are you using? I am not experiencing that in chrome.

Comment: Try `flex: 0 50%;` or  `flex: 0 0 50%;` instead of separate flex-basis and flex-grow. That might work.

Comment: Unfortunately the same result. I'm also using Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, I had `flex-grow:1` on the rest of the items in my local code. Changed it to `flex:1` like in my example, and your solution worked great! Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you use `width` instead of `flex-basis` in the following way:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
}

.flex-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: calc(100% / 6);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #666;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #333;
}

.flex-item:hover {
  width: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the items from growing slightly before shrinking to their final width? If you hover over them in sequence you can see that all the items are growing a tiny bit before settling. If you compare to my code snippet, the items not hovered in that example have a constant width in between the hover changes.